# How to install parsel on Ubuntu machine?

Tags: python, parsel

Please, I have a difficulty installing the parsel

I'm on a machine with Ubuntu 18.04 and python 3.8.2

I installed with the command "pip install parsel", but when I call "from parsel import Selector" it still appears: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'parsel'

I also restarted the machine but the error continues. And when I install it again it appears: Requirement already satisfied

I'm using virtualenv and my pip version is 20.1.1

Please, in Ubuntu is there another way that should be used for installation?

Comment: Do you use any type of virtual environment?

Comment: Thanky @Anwarvic I use this: https://packaging.python.org/key_projects/#virtualenv

Comment: Then, you need to activate this virtualenv by running `source [ENV_NAME]/bin/activate`. Then, install `parsel` like `pip install parsel`. Now, your code should work just fine

Comment: Thank you again @Anwarvic Sorry for not being clear enough before. I already did that and it doesn't work. The strange thing is that other libraries (unidecode, pandas etc.), I did the installation and work normally, except the parsel

Comment: It may help for you to write the commands you executed in the order of execution, including any errors or warnings.